# Fill html input with zeros (0)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Guys i need to fill out an input with zero, to always have 6 characters.
Exemple:
User enters the number 23, while he type, the others 4 characters are 0:

```
    000000 (start)

    000002 (type 2)

    000023 (type 3)
```

I do some searches, but not found and i have no ideia how to do this ;/

Comment: Hey, here you have a good one. Much better than the answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-pad-a-value-with-leading-zeros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution possible :

```js
var el = document.getElementById('el');
var updatetext = function(){
  el.value = ('000000' + el.value).slice(-6);
}
  
el.addEventListener("keyup", updatetext , false);
```

```html
<input id='el' type = 'text' value='000000'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
function padSix(x) 
{
  if (x <= 999999) 
  { 
     x = ("00000"+ x).slice(-6); 
  }
  return x;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n4pvabj0/)**