# How to add zeros into HTML input?

Tags: html

I have a html input that has a fixed length of 7.
If the users types 1234, how can I prefix this input with a number of zeros in order to have the required length of 7?

I want to do this only in the UI because I already have a method in ts code for prefixing with zeros this input in order to send this correctly to backend.

```
 <input formControlName="userNumber" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User #" aria-label="userNumber" aria-describedby="userNumber">
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fill html input with zeros (0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33124806/fill-html-input-with-zeros-0)

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of `input` event on input field. Once user enters some numbers and then when the input field loses focus, required number of zeroes will be added.

```js
const $input = document.querySelector('input');

$input.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  const value = e.target.value;
  const length = e.target.value.length;
  
  if (length === 0) {
     $input.value = value;
  }
  else if (length < 7) {
    $input.value = '0'.repeat(7-length) + value;
  }
});
```

```html
<input formControlName="userNumber" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User #" aria-label="userNumber" aria-describedby="userNumber">
```